# Xamarin.Android Swipe to Refresh in MVVMCross loader loading infinitely

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, swiperefreshlayout

My code is

**.AXML file**

```
<MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    local:MvxBind="Refreshing IsBusy;RefreshCommand RefreshCommand">
```

**my view model**

```
       private MvxCommand refreshCommand;
       public ICommand RefreshCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return refreshCommand ?? (refreshCommand = new MvxCommand(ExecuteRefreshCommand));
            }
        }

        private bool m_IsBusy;

        public new bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return m_IsBusy; }
            set
            {
                m_IsBusy = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsBusy);
                BaseMessage = m_IsBusy ? "Refreshing..." : string.Empty;
            }
        }

        async private void ExecuteRefreshCommand()
        {
          await Task.Run(() => { m_IsBusy = false; });
        }
```

I can able to see the loader,loader is loading indefinitely , but couldn't able to stop the Swipe to refresh loader.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross.Android.Support/Core.UI/MvxSwipeRefreshLayout.cs) of `MvxSwipeRefreshLayout` you can see it inherits from `SwipeRefreshLayout`. `SwipeRefreshLayout` contains a boolean `Refreshing`. This indicates wether it's loading and thus a loading icon should be shown. Setting this to false will hide the animation.

You can do this by binding to it. Create an extra property for example `isRefreshing` in your ViewModel like:

```
private bool _isRefreshing;
public bool IsRefreshing
{
    get { return _isRefreshing; }
    set
    {
        _isRefreshing = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsRefreshing);
    }
}
```

Now in your view bind actually bind the two like:

```
<MvxSwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    local:MvxBind="Refreshing IsRefreshing; RefreshCommand RefreshCommand">
```

Now you have to manually set the boolean to false when your 'refresh work' is done. For example:

```
public IMvxCommand RefreshCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand(async () => {

            // This simulates some refresh work which takes 3 seconds
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            IsRefreshing = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the missing part of "Refreshing IsRefreshing", thanks for your answer

Comment: Thanks,yes boolean binding has been done and updated my query also ,@JKL is there any way to bind BaseMessage = m_IsBusy ? "Refreshing..."?, i couldn't find the way to bind a message?